# Select2 com estilização incorreta

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-select2

Estou usando um select2, porém o estilo dele esta vindo de um modo que não era o esperado. Dessa maneira:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

- Como eu faço pra ele se adequar e ficar alinhado com o input-group?

Código HTML:

```
<div class="form-row">
    <label for="cidade">Cidade</label>
    <div class="input-group">
         <select id="cidade" name="cidade" class="form-control input-bairro"></select>
         <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon3"><i class="icofont icofont-plus"></i></span>
   </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $('#cidade').select2({
          dropdownParent: $('#mdCreateBairros'),
      });
    </script>
</div>
```

Javascript que inicia o select2:

```
$('#cidade').select2({
    dropdownParent: $('#mdCreateRegioes'),
});
```

Comment: qual versão do bootstrap?

Comment: Bootstrap v4.0.0-beta

Comment: Estou construindo um JSFiddle com o seu código. Da onde vem o label "Cidade"?

Comment: Adicionei mais algumas coisas do código @nbkhope

Comment: Ja tentou usar classes para definir o tamanho das colunas? https://jsfiddle.net/229pgz9c/8/ (Referencia: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/#form-grid)

Comment: Tente tambem o inline-form: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/#inline-forms

Comment: O problema, é que mesmo sem o input-group, o select2 fica daquele maneira inadequada